# Cordova App - IOS build failed on Appflow, Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 31

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-appflow

IOS build keeps failing on Appflow, every other plugin were installed except for firebasex and onesignal, have tried almost all solutions online which include installing phonegap-plugin-push all still not working, i will appreciate if anyone can help with solution error below on appflow:

*Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebasex': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 31 Error output:

*Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 31
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/ionic/builds/smartacedeveloper/HOR-Cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:136:25)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
Failed to restore plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin". You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 31*

also see my Ionic Info,
Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.8
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.3

@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1002.0

@angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8

@angular/cli                  : 10.0.8

@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : not installed

Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0, ios 6.2.0

Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0,
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res (update available: 0.15.3) : 0.15.1

native-run (update available: 1.3.0)   : 1.1.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\GOLD AND DIAMOND\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)

NodeJS            : v14.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)

npm               : 6.14.10

OS                : Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

Try running this:

```
brew update;
brew upgrade;
pod repo update
```

Many people fixes the problem just with 'pod repo update'.

If it doesn't work, make sure you do **not** run pod install as admin and that permissions for all the folders and files in the ionic project (not only iOS folder) are not locked. Right-click on folder, obtain information. In the popup, at the bottom, touch the locker, write your Mac's password, and after that there's a dropdown to the left, select 'Apply to included items' (to apply recursively).

If still doesn't work make sure you're using the last version of each plugin.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, I was trying everything all the day and only this advice helped me!!